# How to format a footnote in a table

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have a table where I report the best accuracy observed using 3 different ways and 3 different classifiers. In order to have a smaller table, I present the best accuracy over the 3 classifiers as this:

```
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Accuracy for each features set as reported from the best classifier} %added
\label{Results} %added
\begin{center} %added
\begin{tabular}{llccc}
\hline
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Features Set} & \textbf{Raw} & \textbf{PCA} & \textbf{mRMR} \\ \hline
1 & Example1& 0.90 & 0.91 & 0.92 \\
2 & Example2 & 0.80 & 0.81 & 0.82 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I want to add a footnote on each accuracy that indicates the classifier that reported the specific result e.g. 1 for KNN, 2 for SVM and 3 for RF like this: 0.90$^{1}$. Any tip on how I can make this?

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use the `center` env to center inside a float. It **and** the float provides vertical spacing => double v spacing. Replace `\begin{center}` by `\centering` and delete `\end{center}`

Comment: You never use footnotes in a table, instead you use table notes that are added to the table itself instead of at the bottom of the page. See the `threeparttable` package (and perhaps its extension `threeparttablex`)

Comment: Sorry, but what is KNN, SVM, and RF?

Comment: KNN: K-Nearest Neighbors, SVM: Support Vector Machine and RF: Random Forests. They are Machine Learning classifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    \SetTblrStyle{head}{font=\small}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{foot}{font=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Accuracy for each features set as reported from the best classifier}, 
  label = {Results},
note{1} = {text for the first table note},
note{2} = {text for the second table note}, 
                ]{colspec= {ll*{3}{S[table-format=1.2{1}]}},
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
                  }
    \toprule
No.     & Features Set  & {{{Raw}}} & {{{PCA}}} & {{{mRMR}}}    \\
    \midrule
    1   & Example1\TblrNote{1} 
                        & 0.90\TblrNote{2} 
                                    & 0.91      & 0.92          \\
    2   & Example 2     & 0.80      & 0.81      & 0.82          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Happy New year, first time I head about `tabularray.sty`, thanks for sharing...

Comment: @MadyYuvi, Happy new Year to you too. `tabularray` is relatively new, but it has been available for over a year :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer & happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE.... Hope the below `MWE` can meet your expectation:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Accuracy for each features set as reported from the best classifier} %added
\label{Results} %added
\begin{tabular}{llccc}
\toprule
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Features Set} & \textbf{Raw} & \textbf{PCA} &
\textbf{mRMR} \\  
\midrule
1 & Example1\tnote{1}& 0.90\tnote{2} & 0.91 & 0.92 \\
2 & Example2 & 0.80 & 0.81 & 0.82 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1]...text for first table note
\item[2]...text for second table note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I think you need a `\centering` instruction before `\begin{threeparttable}`, though.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the pointer, shall I modify `MWE` as you advised? Also, thanks for your `+1` Happy New Year...

Comment: Thanks for the good wishes. Happy New Year to you too. Yes, you Should edit your MWE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer & happy new year!

Comment: @giakou4 please accept the suggestion (either mine or `Zarko's`) which suits with you, then please accept it by click the `tick` mark....